# How do I randomly select unique numbers from a given range

Tags: lua

My goal is to use Lua to count to 1000 then randomly get rid of half of the numbers and then list them to me. 
Here's what I have so far.

```
i = 1
while i <= 1000 do
    print(i)
    i = i + 1
end
for i=1, 500, 1 do
    print(math.random(i))
end
```

The problem with this is that the random numbers this code generates can repeat themselves. I need this behaviour to stop.

Answer (score 0):

Put them all in an array and randomly remove half.

```
math.randomseed(os.time())
local nums = {}

for i = 1,1000 do
    num[i] = i
    print(i)
end
for i = 1,500 do
    print(table.remove(nums, math.random(#nums)))
end
nums = nil
```

Comment: Note that this has potentially disastrous performance! Where results from `math.random` are `r`, and the number of elements you have is `N`, this will result in the list being shifted `N - r` times, per iteration. At a thousand numbers, not too big of a deal. Tens or hundreds of thousands and you will feel it slow down. A million? Hope you have a good book to read.

Comment: @Oka I'm not sure what question *you* read, but he only needs it for 1000 numbers for what sounds like a simple exercise for learning the language. Hardly enough to go through the trouble of performing a shuffle on the array for optimzation.

Comment: We're discussing your answer here, and I'm simply letting you know that this has a potential runtime _approaching_ O(n2). It's very easy to get curious, and add two more zeroes to your number - then you're sitting there for 45 seconds wondering what's wrong with your algorithm.

Comment: And with regards to my answer it is concise and perfect for his problem. It does exactly what he asks without bringing in unnessecary additional things to deal with. The logic is easy to understand for a beginner in the language.

Answer (score 0):

One efficient way of doing this is to start by initializing a random list of numbers from 1 - 1000. To do this we can implement an ["inside out"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_.22inside-out.22_algorithm) Fisher-Yates style shuffle.

Always remember to seed your PRNG!

```
math.randomseed(os.time())

local function random_numbers (from, to)
    local set = {}

    for index = from, to do
        local place = math.random(index)

        if place ~= index then
            set[index] = set[place]
        end

        set[place] = index
    end

    return set
end

local numbers = random_numbers(1, 1000)
```

The matter of printing them comes down to only looking at half (or a section equalling one half) of the numbers.

```
for i = 1, 500 do
    print(numbers[i])
end
```

If you truly want to discard half of the numbers, you should iterate through and clear the back half of the list. This will make sure the list remains dense.

```
for i = 501, 1000 do
    t[i] = nil
end
```

Comment: Seems a bit overkill to me. Also he wants to print the numbers he's removing, not the ones left over.

Comment: @warspyking Understanding runtime complexity is never overkill, nor is learning basic shuffling techniques. Also, the question is slightly ambiguous - counting the ones left over and the ones removed is logically equivalent when dealing with halves.

Comment: Understanding it is fine, but for a basic task/exercise for learning the language, a shuffle is hardly necessary. He likely wanted logic he could understand and grasp as a beginner so that he could further his knowledge of the language before jumping right into the big stuff.